# Table for Each User with a Table Stored under a Guild ID inside or a Guild ID with all the users ID's

Tags: mongodb

Okay, the Title is pretty confusing and I couldn't think of how to make it sound better. My question is, if I need to store data inside each user, should I do it where I create a Table for each guild or create a table for each user? I will be storing data inside of it such as XP.

This is for a Discord bot and I am using mongodb to store the data.

Edit: If you need any more clarification let me know.

Comment: Yes, your title is very confusing and it will not attract users to view your question. Please come-up with something meaningful and easy to understand. Please read this carefully https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a table for each user, where you can include the guild that they belong to.

You could also store a table for a guild, which stores the sum of all the attributes of the users, but you definitely need to have the tables for the user before you can do that.